# Mocking @pnp/logging in Jest

Tags: jestjs, mocking, ts-jest, pnp-js

I'm working in a Spfx project.
I have my own Logger class which is a wrapper around the @pnp/logging/Logger.

```
import * as pnpLogging from '@pnp/logging';
export class Logger {
    public static debug(message: string, notify = false, caller: string = null): void {
        pnpLogging.Logger.log( ... )
    }
```

This logger is then used in various other classes, components and hooks.

```
import { Logger } from "./logging";
Logger.debug('some debug message);
```

When creating tests for one of those other classes, jest throws a non-supported exception when importing the @pnp/logging.

I was able to overcome this issue with `office-ui-fabric-react` by using their commonjs libraries.

```
"office-ui-fabric-react/lib/(.*)$": "office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/$1",
```

However, I don't see this option with @pnp/logging.
I also tried to mock it but without success.

```
import { nameof } from './utils';
const mockedPnpLogger = { error: (message) => { } };
jest.mock('@pnp/logging', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@pnp/logging') as any,
  Logger: mockedPnpLogger
}));   
describe('utils', () => { ... }
```

But that's still throwing an error of export

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  3 | const mockedPnpLogger = { error: (message) => { } };
  4 | jest.mock('@pnp/logging', () => ({
> 5 |     ...jest.requireActual('@pnp/logging') as any,
    |             ^
  6 |     Logger: mockedPnpLogger
  7 | }));
  8 |
```

I'm a little lost now with options. Anyone has some insight or can help me in the right direction?

The full error message

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

C:\Development\Projects\Skan\Applications\FuhrPark\src\client\node_modules\@pnp\logging\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from "./logger.js";
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

> 1 | import * as pnpLogging from '@pnp/logging';
```

Jest Configuration

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
        "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/(.*)$": "office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/$1",
        "^@fuhrpark/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/webparts/fuhrpark/$1",
        "^@shared/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/shared/$1"
    },
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/(?!office-ui-fabric-react)"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
        "**/src/**/*.tests.+(ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
        "<rootDir>/src/webparts/fuhrpark/tests/tests-setup.ts"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
        "json",
        "lcov",
        "text",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/test-results",
    "reporters": [
        "default",
        "jest-junit"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
        "global": {
            "branches": 0,
            "functions": 0,
            "lines": 0,
            "statements": 0
        }
    }
},
"jest-junit": {
    "output": "./test-results/summary-jest-junit.xml"
}
```

TypeScript config

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.2/includes/tsconfig-web.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "inlineSources": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@fuhrpark/*": [
        "webparts/fuhrpark/*"
      ],
      "@shared/*": [
        "shared/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the get method on the web object in a function and finally I got it right by creating the mock below. My wrapper is using a .then pattern which is the reason for the double promise resolve in the mock.

**IMPORTANT** the mock can't be inside a it/test or describe, it must be on the top level as also stated in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks)

I also mocked the sp.setup function in the same mock as that was throwing an error otherwise. Accordingly - you need to set up a double as per my finding. I have tried ts-sinon/ts-mockito etc but nothing took me all the way.

```js
jest.mock('@pnp/sp', () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        sp: {
            setup: jest.fn(),
            web: {
                get: () => Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve({ Title: 'Contoso Web Title' }))
            }
        }
    };
});
```

edit: adding an example including a "select" - this also has to be mocked/stubbed

```js
jest.mock('@pnp/sp', () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        sp: {
            setup: jest.fn(),
            web: {
                select: () => {
                    return {
                        get: () => Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve({ Title: 'Contoso Web Title' }))
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Thorild. Your example is perfectly working.